# power bi embedded, change connection string for direct query

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded

I get an error when following step 7 (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/) in the console app to update the connection strings for a direct query connection.

I tried to complete step 7 by providing the connection string to my db from azure and just replacing user name and password.

The error that the console app produces is a red message saying "Bad Request"

Without being able to complete this step 7, the web app with the embedded report produces the following error:

Couldn't load the data for this visual

Error CodeDMTS_DatasourceHasNoCredentialError

Comment: When you created the PBIX file in Power BI Desktop did you choose the "Import" or "Direct Query" option.  In both cases they connect to your underlying data source, but only the "Direct Query" option will allow you to change the connection string / credentials after import.

Comment: I just tried both Import and Direct Query option, when performing step 7 to uopdate the connection, both work with no problem, I am using Azure SQL for testing by the way. Thus, I don't think that option matters. I would suggest you set breakpoints and debug locally to get more information. The error "**CodeDMTS_DatasourceHasNoCredentialError**" indicates that there's no credential for the datasource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 7 finally worked.

I understood step 7 after looking the following link that shows its code (line 500): 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/blob/master/ProvisionSample/Program.cs

Just to be clear, the "Username: " and "Password: " to provide on this step correspond to the Azure SQL credentials. 
I could skip the step: "Connection String (enter to skip): " given the connection was defined on the PBIX report uploaded.
The report was using Direct Query.
After completing step 7, the report is working on the web app.

Comment: Did you manage to execute the last line in Step 7? ("PatchDatasource") I always get a NotFound exception although I'm able to update the connectionstring.

Comment: I don't remember executing a "PatchDatasource" line at the end of Step 7. All I have seen in my case in step 7 has been "Username", "Password" and then "Connection String (enter to skip): " and this way I have been able to embed my reports.

Comment: Use fiddler to get the real exception (Not found might have a body eg 
7A
{"error":{"code":"FeatureNotAvailableError","pbi.error":{"code":"FeatureNotAvailableError","parameters":{},"details":[]}}}
0

 hope that the June release will bubble the error message to the caller

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition that will maybe to help someone. If you need to change also connection string, you should state it in following format:

`Data Source=xxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=dbName;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;`

Credit goes to Nithya from PBI forum: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/PowerBI-Embedded-Sample-Connection-string/td-p/27454

Comment: Thanks, Nithya's solution worked in my case too. P.S. I hope Power BI /Azure teams will make some enhancements to make this power bi embedded report update a less daunting task in the near future

Comment: Do not do this as the password will be in plain text and can be retrieved using client.Datasets.GetDatasources(). Ideally, SQL would be enabled and used instead

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue today. The new CLI does not work to do step 7 right now. You get bad request. Go to GitHub and download an older version. I did that, allowed me to set connection string and it all started working.